# Mount External HDD using OpenElec

Tags: kodi, hard-drive, openelec

I have a pi with Openelec and I have an external HDD, powered. When I go into the file management section of settings I can't find my HDD. I am assuming that Openelec/XBMC is not auto mounting the drive. Do I need to ssh in to mount the drive and add a script to make sure that it is mounted when the pi boots up? If so could someone point me in that direction? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [fstab](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/fstab.html) would make a good pointer.

Comment: Sweet thanks for the info that should get me what I need.